# Track the number of actual downloads in Orangedox

Tags: orangedox

I have a number of Microsoft Word templates that I share with my friends and I would like to know how many times the templates have been downloaded and not the number of times they have viewed them in their web browser. Clicking on a shared-link to a Word document lets the receiver view the document in the web browser and that shows up as a download in Orangedox, but I am only interested in how many times they have actually clicked on the download button and saved the file to their computer.

My question is if there is a way in Orangedox to only track the number of actual downloads of a file and not how many times they have actually clicked on the shared link (i.e. viewed the file through their web browser)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way to see the number of times the file was downloaded and not just viewed using the Dropbox landing page.  When creating the link using PRO you can select the "direct download" feature which will skip the Dropbox landing page and force the user to automatically download the Word document.

Here's a coupon for two months free of PRO

> db.pro.STACK.FALL

https://dropbox.orangedox.com/plans/

Also our release 2 will be coming out at the end of the month that will allow PRO users to monitor views as well as downloads